# Cannot redirect X on 19.04

Tags: xorg, 19.04

I've just installed Ubuntu 19.04 in a virtual machine. Trying to redirect all X output to a remote X server by putting the `DISPLAY=someLANip:0.0` environment variable in `/etc/environment`. It works perfectly fine with Mint 19.1 but no luck with Ubuntu 19.04: it is sill rendering the desktop on the localhost. When I `echo $DISPLAY`, I get `:0` and can't figure out what is overwriting it. Does anyone have any clues, please?

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `DISPLAY` variable in `~/.profile` did the trick but it wasn't worth for me anyway as the Ubuntu 19.04 graphics performance over remote X server turned out pretty terrible.